# Apache Marathon/Docker Swarm: containers keep repeating

Tags: apache, docker, marathon, docker-swarm

I have a very simple container which says "hello world"

I have successfully run them and scale them to X.

They all seem to be in a cycle where they would run it then sleep for a bit then run it again.

Marathon cycle would be: `Waiting, Running, Delaye`d and repeat
Swarm cycle woulbd be: `Ready, Running, Shutdown` and repeat

How do i specify so that the container finishes after first execution whether in swarm or marathon?

Answer (score 0):

You can not, both Swarm and Marathon are designed for long running services.

For running something just one time you should use plain `docker run` command in Swarm and some [other](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/frameworks/) framework in Mesos (Marathon run on Mesos) e.g. [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) which is cron replacement for Mesos and runs tasks periodically.

Comment: I want to use mesos load balancing via marathon framework so i want to run stuff through marathon but short-lived containers

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/#/step-6-communicate-with-the-swarm as for Marathon you can use Mesos DNS with srv recors: https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/naming.html

Comment: first one is about `docker run` in swarm and second about alternative for loadbalancer: mesos dns

Comment: i've started docker swarm cluster with the command: docker swarm so that doesnt work for me. and I would like to use mesos through marathon (the whole point of container orchestration, right?) maybe it just doesnt fit my need

Comment: As I wrote earlier Marathon is designed to long running tasks so you try to do something against it very purpose. AFAIK `docker swarm` command is just shortcut and you still should be able to run regular commands.